# Add percent to numbers

Tags: javascript, math

How can I add percent to a sum? I have tried `var sum = 3.25 + '3.4%';` but it didn't work. I'm just getting `0.00` as an answer.

Comment: Is it like a question to get upvotes? Pretty basic and can be googled easily

Comment: `3.25 + '3.4%'` results `'3.253.4%'` rather than `0.00`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To "add a percent to a number" means "multiply the number by `(1 + pct)`":

```
var sum = 3.25;
sum = sum * (1 + 0.034);
```

You could equivalently skip the `1` (that's just the way I think about it) and add:

```
var sum = 3.25;
sum += sum * 0.034;
```

So if you're starting off with a string representation of a percentage, you can use `parseFloat()` to make it a number:

```
var pct = "3.4%"; // or from an <input> field or whatever

pct = parseFloat(pct) / 100;
```

The `parseFloat()` function conveniently ignores trailing non-numeric stuff like the "%" sign. Usually that's kind-of a problem, but in this case it saves the step of sanitizing the string.

Comment: Many thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: @ErikEdgren ok good luck!  Be prepared for some results that look funny sometimes (repeating fractions where you might think you'd get a clean quotient, for example). [See this classic old question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use arithmetic operators.

var sum = 3.25

sum += sum *= 0.034;

< 3.3605

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation and number adding using the same + symbol. You need to use () around the numbers.

```
var sum = (3.25+3.4)+"%";
```

Answer (score 0):

let's assume that you want to add x percent to the current number :

const percentage =  14.5;    let number = 100    const numberPlusPercentage = number + number / 100  * percentage
console.log('result = 'numberPlusPercentage.toFixed(2))

result = 114.5