# How to format value to Currency or Percent in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

What is the best way of formating the values to percentage or currency from `Ajax` and display to a `Table`?

I'm currently developing an application which has Money values from `SQL` `Server` and need to be format from **3569.09** to **$ 3, 569.09** and also from **24.55** to **24.55 %** on the `Table`.

I have the tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551394/add-percent-to-numbers) but still did not help.

Here is JS my Code:

```
function loadMarginBelow21() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Dashboard/MarginBelow21",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Stock+ '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Price + '</td>'; //Must show Currency sign in the beguining like $5,664.00
                html += '<td>' + item.Source + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.COST + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Margin + '</td>'; // Must show % at the end of value
                //html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.Stock+ ')">Edit</a></td>';// | <a href="#" onclick="Delele(' + item.EmployeeID + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '<td>' +sdg + '</td>'
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbodyM').html(html);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Currently the table shows like:

[image]

Comment: you could use an additional js plugin: http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: why not `Item.margin+'%'`??

Comment: @vibhor1997a, I have tried that too. But the Data still the same. I'm using a modal to display the data of the table. I don't know if that could be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) is your friend. Create a new formatter with a locale and currency (I’ll assume you want US dollars here) and it’ll produce formatted strings.

```
let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
let price = formatter.format(item.Price);
```

Given your sample data it looks like the percentage can just be added on to the end using string concatenation.

Comment: I will try that now, But what about the % value? How to display that sign next to the value?

Comment: `html += '<td>' + item.Margin + '%</td>'`? Just include the percentage sign in the closing string.

Comment: Thanks very much. All your examples works and I hope it's may also help someone else in the future. much appreciate.